# Agent population & Process modeling

Tags: anylogic

I have an agent population called "product" with parameters that change for each product[i] according to a database. So let's assume each has a different "productId".

I want to inject this population, in the order it was created into a process modelling flow chart: "Source" -> (Delay) -> (Sink)

Additionally I want to retrieve the "productId" and apply it to a variable when the product[i] passes the Delay.

I am wondering if it is possible. I haven't found anything and wasn't able to do it.

Comment: if you've already created all the agents previously (when building the population from the database), you can use an enter block instead of a source. You just create a function (or write your code on the main On Startup) that goes through the population (it will be ordered by creation) and send those agents to the enter block.
Regarding the delay, if the agent carries a parameter (ProcessingTime) you can place agent.ProcessingTime in the processing time field.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a source you must use a enter block as you can see in the following image:
[image: enter]

the agents created on the enter block are of the type Product and you can make your agents go to the agent block in the order they were created using this function in the event that I triggered after 1 second:

```
for(Product a : products){
    enter.take(a);
}
```

And the code to retrieve the productId is just in the exit of the delay block.
YourVariable=agent.productId